# Why is my SD card having errors every day?

Tags: windows-11, sd-card, micro-sd-card

### Problem

I have a Minecraft Server on my MicroSD Card, which I connect to my computer using a MicroSD Card to SD Card adapter. Every day, when I try to write something to the server properties file using VS code, it throws this error:

```
Failed to save 'server.properties': Unable to write file 'd:\Java Server\server.properties' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'd:\Java Server\server.properties')
```

I am able to fix this by doing a drive repair, but then the next day, the same error pops up.

### Questions

- Why does this happen?
- How can I stop this error from ever happening again?

Comment: This is pretty expected behaviour for SD Cards, which tents to die quicker, especially when using them a lot. I'd recommend backing up the important settings and buying another one, so you won't lose any files. It could also be that the adapter is to blame. any chance you have another?

Comment: @Netan does sticking a label on the adapter cause errors?

Comment: Throw the card in the trash, SD (and other flash cards) are expendable.

Comment: It is dead. Get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mitigate these errors because of the nature of media. All (based on current technology) flash products (SD, CF, SSD) have limited cycles of write and after some time you should throw and replace. The problem is especially with SD and so cards because they have small contacts which subject of errors from vibrations and other mechanical actions.

To make it more reliable run the software from harddisk (mechanical or SSD).