# Corrupt SD card showing as unallocated space on disk management

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, disk-space, sd-card, micro-sd-card

My SD card showing **corrupt** on my android phone. I then through SD card reader attach it to pc. When open it in disk management it showing as **unallocated space** and not accessible at all.

Disk Management:
[image: see this]

- I have execute the `mountvol` command which will tell me this as the volume with no mount points and i performed `chkdsk` command it shows no error.

[image: see this]

- There is a lot of data on my sd card and 59.6 GB total sd card storage but unallocated showing only 7.40 GB space.

What should i try to access sd card data? Any solution?

Comment: Very likely dead.

Comment: 511999 KB is ~511MB. not much space at all compared to the 7.4GB.

Comment: Throw the card in the trash, SD (and other flash cards) are expendable.

Comment: if you want to recover data using common data formats like images, I believe this is exactly what photorec was made for, though of course no data recovery scenario is ever guaranteed to produce results.

Comment: @RomeoNinov What does it means?

Comment: @FrankThomas mistakenly written as 511999 Kb, original storage of my sd card is 59.6 GB

Comment: @Legendplayer, what part of my comment you do not get? Also check this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1794771/409497

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, this Q/A is mainly focused on harddisks.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/241829/705502: Same general steps apply IF the device is detected with correct capacity. If not you're most likely dealing with firmware/NAND issue which in general isn't DIY-able.

Comment: A 64GB card showing up as 8GB is quite likely to have been a fake, fine until you tried to write past that real 8GB, then just blows up in your face. **1.** Buy SD cards from supermarkets or local retailers, so you can take them back if they fail early. You're also far less likely to get cheap fakes, unlike buying online from Amazon or eBay. **2.** Never keep the only copy of any data on something as fragile as an SD card. Even the good ones have a remarkable propensity for sudden total failure.

Answer (score 0):

In general for DIY data recovery the drive, the SD card in your case, needs to be detected with correct capacity.

[image]

If it's not, 99 out of 100 times you're dealing with a firmware issue, which in turn is the result of degraded NAND.

Firmware can not be repaired, instead a data recovery specialist will bypass it and read NAND directly and simulate the firmware algorithms used to manage data on the NAND using specialized software ([example](https://youtu.be/Qo5zynp2eWc)).